# Resort one array based on another array

Tags: powershell, sorting, enumerable

I am looking to resort one array based on another array. In a previous project I needed to just get a list of the disordered items, and applying that code to my current scenario I get this

```
$definedSet = @('C', 'B', 'D', 'A')
$history = @('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

$disordered = $history.Where({-not [Linq.Enumerable]::SequenceEqual([string[]]$history, [string[]]$definedSet)})
$disordered
```

Which does indeed give me a list of all four items, because they are all out of order.
However, in this new scenario I need to resort `$history` based on `$definedSet`. The key being that there could be items in one that aren't in the other. But I am starting with a simpler problem, and that has me stumped. I feel certain `[Linq.Enumerable]` is the key, obviously, but my Google-Fu is not pointing me towards a solution. I have tried the Microsoft Docs article on the Enumerable class, and my brain... melted.

Comment: If I understand correctly, `$history | Sort-Object { $definedSet.IndexOf($_) }` is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: Oh, my. That was me REALLY making things harder than they need to be. :)

Comment: You need to define what to do for values not found in the set (in your question) but that should do it. Also note this method is case sensitive!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case you can **sort by index**, using [Array.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=net-6.0):

```bash
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
int IList.IndexOf(System.Object value)
```

However it's worth noting this method is **case-sensitive**. If you wish to find indexes with a **case-insensitive** method you can use [Array.FindIndex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findindex?view=net-6.0#system-array-findindex-1(-0()-system-predicate((-0)))):

```bash
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
static int FindIndex[T](T[] array, System.Predicate[T] match)
static int FindIndex[T](T[] array, int startIndex, System.Predicate[T] match)
static int FindIndex[T](T[] array, int startIndex, int count, System.Predicate[T] match)
```

Or you can initialize the set as a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-6.0) and use it's [`FindIndex(Predicate<T>)` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-list-1-findindex(system-predicate((-0)))).

Both options should use a [*case-insensitive* equality comparer (`-eq` / `-ne`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#-eq-and--ne) in their [`Predicate<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-6.0).

[`Sort-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/sort-object?view=powershell-7.2) allows you to sort by [multiple expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.2#sort-object), in the example below it will sort first by the found index in the set and then *alphabetically*:

```bash
$definedSet = 'powershell', 'is', 'awesome'
$history = 'Awesome', 'PowerShell', 'set', 'not in', 'is'
$predicate = [Predicate[string]] { $args[0] -eq $_ }
$history | Sort-Object { [array]::FindIndex($definedSet, $predicate) }, { $_ }
```